# why am i getting nzec error and EOFerror in this python code at line 4 on codechef?

Tags: python-3.x

when i run this code on codechef i am getting nzec and EOF error,but i am not getting any errors on the Jupyter notebook while running this code please help!

```
s=""    #empty string
import random
a=int(input(""))                      #to input an integer
b=int(input(""))                      #to input another integer
c=a-b                                 #subtracting them
d=str(c)                              #converting the result to string 
l=len(d)                              #calculating its length 
r=random.randint(0,l)                 #generating a random number to choose 
                                      #a string index
new_number=random.randint(1,10)       #generating another random number to 
                                      #replace a number in the string
string_new_number=str(new_number)     #converting the random number to 
                                      #string
for i in range(0,l):                  
    if i==r:
        s=s+string_new_number        #changing the string with the new 
                                     #generated number
    else:
        s=s+d[i]                     
print(s)
```

Comment: Can we see the full stacktrace?

Comment: what is stacktrace?

Comment: The error message you get when you try to run your code.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 4, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line